# "Deploy processes and flows as active" not available in Enterprise/Developer orgs

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

As per the documentation says, `Deploy processes and flows as active` checkmark should be available in `Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions`.

`Customize Application` permission is active for the given profile.

That said, I can only visualise that field in `Unlimited` org edition.
It would be nice to know if this is a documentation issue or permission issue. Anyone more with the same issue?

Following is a screenshot of `Process Automation Settings` in a Developer Org, where that field is not visible:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_deploy_as_active.htm), This setting doesn't appear in non-production orgs (such as scratch, sandbox, and developer orgs) because you can always deploy a new active version.  Hence you are not able to find this option in your developer org.

Thanks

Comment: Documentation regarding the field is outdated then :( I have raised it to SF. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to defeat the purpose of testing flow deployment and running a test in sandboxes first. If the flow isn't active, the tests aren't running with the new flow active. So it is not an accurate test of deployment to production. So what I am having to do is manually put the flow in the sandbox, activate it, then run my deployment/tests.